# What's the song in Naruto Shippuden 423 at the time 9:20 when Sakura teaches them how to make food pills?

Tags: naruto, music

What's the song in Naruto Shippuden 423 at the time 9:20 when Sakura teaches them how to make food pills?

Answer (score 1):

It is an unreleased track called "Minato Saves Kushina". [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=en6t6R41ccs) it is on Youtube.